# c# .Net Core 2.1 Authorize Attribute - Default Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, authorize-attribute

When using the [Authorize] Attribute (without specifying a policy), is there a way to set a required claim on the default policy?

The point being i would like it to require a claim to authorize, but i don't want to have to explicitly set the policy for the controllers. I'd rather just have [Authorize] not [Authorize(Policy = "something")]

Another way to ask this is, is it possible to add a claim to the default policy?

Thanks in advance for any and all ideas and opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override default policy in startup

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                      .RequireClaim("CLAIM")
                                      .Build();
});
```

Also if you want to authorize by some custom policy and avoid writing the policy multiple times, you can create a new authorize attribute

```
public class AuthorizePolicyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizePolicyAttribute()
    {
        Policy = "CustomPolicy";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent a false positive error (i.e. You forget to put the [Authorize] attribute in one of your hundreds of action methods or controllers and a skilled hacker somehow reached that endpoint) you can also add a convention to your controllers so that they are automatically having the [Authorize] attribute. In case you really do not need the authorization on some action method or controller, then you can use [AllowAnonymous] attribute for it.

First you have to create a new authorizaton policy and add it to your services in your Startup.cs class under ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthorization(o => {    
    o.AddPolicy("authwithsomepolicy", p =>
    {
        p.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        p.RequireClaim("MYPOLICY");
    }); 
});
```

Then you create a new class that extends IControllerModelConvention and makes the automatization for that policy for all of your controllers:

```
public class AddAuthorizeFilters : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("authwithsomepolicy"));            
    }
}
```

And finally in your Startup.cs class you can add this convention to your Mvc system (again under ConfigureServices method):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(setupAction =>
    {
        setupAction.Conventions.Add(new AddAuthorizeFilters ());
    });
}
```